# Concat sorted Dask DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dask

I have N Dask DataFrame sorted by the `ts` column(no index). I would like to create one DataFrame - concat all of them, but still have it sorted by this `ts` column.

Note: `ts` can overlap between DataFrames.

Can someone recommend efficient way to implement it?

UPDATE:

```
dfs = []
for product in PRODUCTS:
   namespace = PRODUCT_NAMESPACE[product]
   message_type = PRODUCT_MESSAGE_TYPE[product]

   num_expected_channels = PRODUCT_EXPECTED_CHANNELS[product]
   for channel in range(num_expected_channels):
       df = storage.load(
           namespace,
           partition_filter=(P.date == '2022-02-01') & (P.channel == str(channel)),
       )

       df = df.assign(
          product=product,
          message_type=message_type
       ).astype(
          dict(
              dtype='category',
              product=pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(PRODUCTS),
              message_type=pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(['trade', 'quote']),
          )
       ).drop(columns=['channel', 'feed'])

       df = df.set_index('ts', sorted=True, drop=False).persist()

       dfs.append(df)

df = dd.concat(dfs, interleave_partitions=True)
df = df.map_partitions(lambda pdf: pdf.sort_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can append the dataframes and still be sorted, you should look `dask.dataframe.multi.concat`.

You should look into `dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge` if the simple concatenation was to result in a partially sorted dataframe.

EDIT: Credit to [@Michel Delgado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888719/michael-delgado) who pointed out that sorting data across the partitions without an index would be very memory-consuming. You might want to go through the comments below to see more details.

Comment: I was trying to use this method, the only thing I have to use interleave_partitions=True because I have overlaps. The problem with this method - it still requires a lot if memory.

Comment: To be honest, I have never been confronted to this particular issue. But then again, Dask being pretty recent, I don't know if there are other more optimized ways to process them?

Comment: You’re hoping so sort all data across the partitions without an index - this will require a lot of memory no matter what. To reduce memory, make ts or some positional proxy column the index.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I call set_index with sorted=True before using concat and anyway get ‘No disk space’

Comment: no disk space is very different from no memory. If you're running out of disk space you should (a) make sure you have sufficient disk space to write a copy of the data, and (b) inspect the head of your resulting dataframe prior to writing to make sure you don't have mis-aligned or mis-typed columns creating additional columns or coercing numeric columns to objects or something. Please post your code and a full traceback showing this error in order to get the most relevant help. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I think I see where is the issue. During concat with repartition-merge generated subtask I get huge partitions.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have also added a code. set_index in that case triggers compute immediately. Could you please tell if it is correct place for persist to avoid recomputation on save again?

Comment: how big is the data you're working with, and how much memory do you have? persist makes things like shuffling/sorting/reindexing faster, but it brings all the data into memory, so it's definitely not a low-memory option. if you're getting an error it would be really helpful to see the full traceback, too.